# How to change the MySQL prompt from the command line

Tags: mysql, linux, database, prompt, mysql-command-line-client

I bet this is easy and I have surely overseen something:

I am trying to set the "internal" MySQL prompt from the Bash shell as an argument to the command `mysql`.

The manual makes reference a command line option called `--named-command=str` where I assumed that I could pass any of the commands referred here:

[mysql Command-line Client](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql-command-line-client/#prompt-command)

But an version of the command below return an error after connecting to the DB:

```
mysql --named-commands='\R >'
mysql --named-commands="\R >"
```

The error reads:

> Warning: mysql: ignoring option '--named-commands' due to invalid value '\R > '

I thus assume that I am missing something. Please note that I have already gone through the MySQL manual/s (both, the Oracle site and the MariaDB site). The fact is that the question itself is not easy to define as when I t yto google for "Mysql Command line option" it normally takes me to the "internal" MySQL command line (or more exactly, the MySQL command line client).

Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: You seem to be trying to set the prompt, then why don't you use `--prompt='\R >'`? I don't know MySQL, but according to the reference you linked to, `--named-commands` doesn't even take a value... And `--prompt` is obviously for prompt. I don't know how you went through the manual, linked to it yourself, but couldn't spot something so intuitive and obvious. At any rate, not a bash question, editing out the bash tag.

Comment: Not very sure what is the question but you may want to check `$MYSQL_PS1`.

Comment: You are righ! :facepalm: 
I swear I went through all the list a few times, that's why I asked here... sorry mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql -h *hostname* -u *username* -p --prompt *myCustomPrompt*\>

Be sure to escape `>` with `\` in order to avoid a bash syntax error.
See the final section of [mysql client commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) for instructions on special characters to use in the prompt command.

Answer (score 0):

For example, using `--prompt=` or `--prompt`, you can change the default prompt `mysql>`  to `11>`  with login as shown below. *`\R` is the current time, in 24-hour military time (0–23) according to [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690553/can-i-change-the-mysql-prompt-with-selected-database-as-we-do-in-hive/77471378#77471378) explains how to change the default prompt `mysql>`  in detail:

```
mysql -u john -p --prompt='\R> '
...
11>
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p --prompt '\R> '
...
11>
```