# Can I change the mysql prompt with selected database as we do in hive?

Tags: mysql, database, hive, prompt, mysql-command-line-client

In hive, I can set the prompt to be the currently selected database. Is it possible to do the same in MySQL?

I want to replace `mysql` with `kundoor` in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Type this in your terminal

```
export MYSQL_PS1="\u@\h [\d]> "
```

This will create the following

```
user@host [databasename]>
```

Comment: username/host = root@shekh-Latitude-3550  as per above syntax export MYSQL_PS1="\root@\shekh-Latitude-3550 [kundoor]"   shall it fire this command from terminal or from mysql promt.

Comment: @ShekhFirozAlam no only type export MYSQL_PS1="\u@\h [\d]> " in your terminal.

Comment: On Windows (when you are getting "The syntax of the command is incorrect.") you should do:  `set MYSQL_PS1=\u@\h [\d]^> `  (Note the `^` before the `>`)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to using the MYSQL_PS1 environment variable @Noob describes, you can use the `prompt` command within the mysql client:

```
mysql> prompt \u@\h [\d]
```

(type a space at the end of the line to get a space after the prompt)

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html for more on mysql client commands.

You can make this default by editing your [MySQL options file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html):

```
[mysql]
prompt \u@\h [\d]
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, using `--prompt=`(`--prompt`), you can change the default prompt `mysql>` to `apple>`  of `apple` database with login as shown below. *`\d` is the current database but if the current database is not selected, `\d` is `(none)` and `\_` is a space according to [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html):

```
mysql -u john -p --prompt='\d> ' apple
...
apple>
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p --prompt='\d>\_' apple
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p --prompt=\\d\>\\_ apple
```

Or, using `prompt`(`PROMPT`) or `\R`, you can change the default prompt `mysql>` to `apple>`  of `apple` database after login as shown below. *Don't forget to put a space   just after `\d>`:

```
mysql -u john -p apple
...              ↓ A space
mysql> prompt \d> 
PROMPT set to '\d>\_'
apple>
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p apple
...          ↓ A space
mysql> \R \d> 
PROMPT set to '\d> '
apple>
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p apple
...
mysql> prompt \d>\_
PROMPT set to '\d>\_'
apple>
```

Or:

```
mysql -u john -p apple
...
mysql> \R \d>\_
PROMPT set to '\d>\_'
apple>
```

Or on Windows, you can set the prompt under `[mysql]` in `my.ini` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453555/mysql-configuration-file-sections/77456323#77456323) explains `[mysql]` and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597884/where-is-mysqls-my-ini-located-on-windows/77461989#77461989) explains where `my.ini` is located on Windows:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[mysql]
...
prompt='\d> '
```

Or:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[mysql]
...
prompt='\d>\_'
```

Or:

```ini
# "my.ini"

[mysql]
...
prompt=\d>\_
```

Then, you can change the default prompt `mysql>` to `apple>`  of `apple` database with login by setting `my.ini`'s location to `--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` as shown below. *`--defaults-file=` or `--defaults-extra-file=` must be the 1st option otherwise there is [the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836214/problem-with-mysqldump-defaults-extra-file-option-is-not-working-as-expecte/77463030#77463030):

```
mysql --defaults-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john -p apple
...
apple>
```

Or:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file='C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini' -u john -p apple
...
apple>
```